# Why does projected gradient descent only consider the sign of the gradient?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

I am talking about the projected gradient descent (PGD) method in the context of adversarial machine learning. The paper [Towards Deep Learning Models Resistant to Adversarial Attacks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06083.pdf) defines PGD using the following formula on page 4.

$$x^{t+1} = \prod_{x+S} (x^t + \alpha \operatorname*{sgn}(\nabla_x L(\theta, x, y))).$$

Why can't we remove the $\operatorname*{sgn}$ operator, and use the following?

$$x^{t+1} = \prod_{x+S} (x^t + \alpha \nabla_x L(\theta, x, y)).$$

We can always project the gradient back to the $\mathscr{L}_\infty$ box by clipping it after applying the gradient descent, so the constraint isn't really a concern.

Comment: Gradient descent is slow when the residual landscape has narrow elongated valleys, see the standard examples in 2 dimensions. The search directions will dominantly be almost orthogonal to the direction to the minimum. Using the sign or clipping the gradient otherwise is a coarse measure to somewhat equalize the directions so that the component towards the center gains more influence, at least in the average over multiple steps.